# Running Great Expectations on files with spaces in names

Tags: python, great-expectations

I am running Great Expectations on a json file. The folder name has spaces in it.
the filename is as below

```
/mnt/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder name with problem/part-000-tid-1234567-abc-x-y-z.json
```

When i run the validation i get the below error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/databricks/great_expectations/uncommitted/data_docs/local_site/validations/folder%20name%20with%20problem/20230901-212503-my-run-name-template/20231017T212503.475820Z/8137d3b18ba77347392992ed75eef9a1.html does not exist
```

When i remove the spaces from the folder name, the validation runs successfully.
I have tens of such folders and its hard to rename all of them.

Is there a solution to this problem so that the GE would take the folder names with spaces ?

Comment: Please add example how you run your code

Comment: Its a big chunk of inter connected code. Cannot paste the code here. There is a separate notebook that accepts the data files and validates them. I just observed that the error is happening on dbutils.fs.cp, command where it tries to copy the data to the final location but couldn't find the file. "An error occurred while calling o2946.cp."